# How to change 'filter data...' placeholder in dash table python?

Tags: python, html, css, plotly-dash

I have been using dash library in python. In which I use dash table but in the filter data cell I got 'filter data...' as placeholder and I want to change it.

In dash library in python, I use dash table but in the filter data cell I got 'filter data...' as placeholder and I want to change it.

Answer (score 0):

A little late, but you can use the `filter_options` dictionary with the key `placeholder_text`. So, something like:

```
    dash_table.DataTable(
        sort_action='native',    
        filter_action='native',
        filter_options={
           'placeholder_text': 'Type filter...',
           'case': 'insensitive'
        },
```

The above will give you a default case-insensitive filter with the placeholder "Type filter...".